# Linked List implementation: why cannot move to head.next before creating new node

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am solving [a challenge from hackerrank.](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-linked-list/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=legacy&isFullScreen=true)
[This is the description of the question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rT6eo.png)

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;
    Node(int d) {
        data = d;
        next = null;
    }
}

class Solution {

    public static  Node insert(Node head,int data) {
        //Complete this method        
    }

    public static void display(Node head) {
        Node start = head;
        while(start != null) {
            System.out.print(start.data + " ");
            start = start.next;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Node head = null;
        int N = sc.nextInt();

        while(N-- > 0) {
            int ele = sc.nextInt();
            head = insert(head,ele);
        }
        display(head);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

It is basically implementing a Linked List, and I eventually did solve the problem. However I have some question about the code.

This is the correct code which gives the desired output:

```java
    public static  Node insert(Node head,int data) {
        if (head == null) {
        head = new Node(data);
    } else {
        Node current = head;
        while(current.next != null)
            current = current.next;
        current.next = new Node(data);
    }
    return head;
    }
```

This is the incorrect code I wrote at first:

```java
    public static  Node insert(Node head,int data) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node(data);
        } else {
            Node current = head;
            while(current != null)
                current = current.next;     
            current = new Node(data);
        }        
        return head;
    }
```

The difference is the the while loop statement and the code after while loop.
When running the entire java code, using the sample input, the incorrect code only output `2`, where the expected output being `2 3 4 1`

I am guessing it is something about the pointer reference?
But when I break the code into steps, the incorrect code still seems reasonable to me.

- the correct code, `current` stays on `head` before it creates new node with data.
- the incorrect code, `current` goes to `head.next` before it creates new node with data.

[I draw out the steps of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ki1tG.png) (upper is the correct code, below is incorrect code), and end up with two question:

1. Is the incorrect code wrong because what I circled in the image? like I cannot create a node when I am at null? (if that is the case, why no exception error then?)
2. Another things that bothers me is that the code I underline in the image seem equivalent.

Can someone point out why the incorrect code cannot give the desired output? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement:

```
current = new Node(data);
```

...does not mutate the list. It just stores a new node in a *variable*. But the list is not influenced by that assignment. In order to *add* a node to a non-empty list, you'll have to update the `next` attribute of a node, more particularly, the tail node. But the important difference here is between assigning to a local variable (does not influence a list), and to an attribute of a node that is already in the list (that *does* influence the list).

So the job of the code must be to find the tail node. That is what the loop is for. The wrong code, overshoots the last node, and so there is no reference to the tail node when the loop exits. And so -- empty handed -- there is no way to assign the new node to a `next` attribute of the tail node.

Comment: So in the worng code, once current=current.next (in the while loop), current is just a variable with value null, and does not make current equal to the attribute of the node?

Comment: And excuse me, could you explain "there is no way to assign the new node to a next attribute of the tail node."? In my understanding this is the situation in the wrong code but why that's not possible?

Comment: The variable is not an "alias" for a `next` attribute. A variable can be assigned a value, but that only affects what that variable has as value. You can never hope to change an attribute (of a tail node) by assigning to a variable. You really need to assign to that attribute. It's just not how Java works. Such things are possible in C, using the address `&` syntax, but it is not how it works in most other popular languages.

Comment: Thank you for clearing my thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

```
    current = new Node(data);
```

If current is null, this is effectively

null = new Node(data);

which is an error and does not link your list.

null is not the end of your list,
the node that points to null is the end (not null).

And you have to find and hold onto that.